Can the hardwire run behind the dishwasher to the junction box in the next cabinet?
I am replacing a Bosch 100 series that is hardwired at the front of the dishwasher with a Bosch 500 that required a junction box. My dishwasher cabinet is against a wall and the hardwire comes out of a hole from the small space between the wall and the cabinet. The only place the junction box can go is under the sink which is on the other side of the dishwasher. I know you can’t mount the junction box behind the dishwasher but is it ok for that wire to run along the back of the cabinet and through the hole to the junction box under the sink? And if not what are my options.

Some pics would really help you here, but there is generally no problem running a cable through the cabinet wall to a box or outlet under the sink, as long as the cable is protected from damage (e.g. someone rummaging around the sink cabinet).  Since you don't have pics or sketches, it's not clear what you propose, but as long as you have the cable in conduit or ENT (smurf tube) if any part of the run is inside the sink cabinet, you should be OK.

The diagram on page 3 seems to answer your question. Whether that meets code depends on your code.

Thank you so much. Mine came with the wall plug in and I had to purchase the junction box separately. Neither set of instructions has that diagram. Thanks again!

Your title edit wasn't helpful or appropriate. Begging won't get you better or faster answers. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Since you chose hard wired connection you will need disconnecting means that can be locked off https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/4/equipment-for-general-use#422.31_(B) . If you had chose the plug connection the receptacle is required to be in adjacent cabinet https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/4/equipment-for-general-use#422.16_(B)_(2)

@isherwood is that diagram really right, though?  It appears to show an unprotected (romex?) cable coming out of the wall behind the D/W into an adjacent cabinet.

It probably doesn't address cable protection. It's up to you to know local code.

Yes, running the cable behind the dishwasher, through a cabinet, etc. is perfectly fine. The concerns are:

Protect if subject to damage. Not an issue here as the dishwasher blocks most of it. If it extends a significant distance into another cabinet (which would be unusual) then it would need to be protected.
Secured. Again, behind the dishwasher is not an issue. If the junction box is within 12" of the hole through the cabinet then there is no issue in the cabinet. If the junction box is more than 12" from the hold through the cabinet then the cable should secured to the cabinet within 12" of the junction box.

